# Is there any performance difference between IN and NOT IN Operators?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, query-performance

Is there any major query performance difference between `IN` and `NOT IN` operators in oracle database?

Comment: I suppose another view: "Is x NOT IN y equivalent to NOT (y IN x)"? (Where NOT in the second form is taken as a trivial logical negation.)

Comment: Give us a specific query that you're concerned about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like most performance questions, it depends.

If there are no indexes then they should be roughly comparable.

If you have an index on the limiting column then `IN` will likely be faster than `NOT IN` as `IN` can use an index seek while `NOT IN` will require a table scan.

The above depends of course, if there are very few distinct values of `col1` and it's indexed, then `NOT IN` could end up using an index seek rather than a table scan.

Comment: Thanks, Column is a foreign key and that column contains 8 char(3) tokens. That table has around 2200 records and it is not going to grow much. I checked the explain plan for both cases it uses table full scan. I believe, There is not much difference in this case.